# Java System.GC() and Memory Leakage

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I have read up and searched through the forums about leaking memory and gradually increasing RAM. I tried to use the call of System.GC() method every 60 seconds in my program and it seems to be working given that my RAM usage drops every call. Why is it a good idea not to use this method? In every post I have read they seemed to vaguely explain why the method does not free up memory, yet my program seems to say otherwise. Some even said the method did nothing at all but suggest to the Garbage Collector clean itself up. NOTE : My leak is not from static methods I know because I removed them from my entire project and the RAM still increased. I would post my code, but it is rather large so I doubt anyone is up to reading it.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're not really saving anything calling GC.  When the heap fills up GC will be triggered, and there's no real advantage (but there *is* execution cost) in causing it to occur sooner.

Comment: Understand that every time you, say, create a String to be used in a print statement, you (in a way) "leak" the storage for that String, since it's not immediately "reclaimed" when you're done with it.  But that's OK, since GC will find such unused objects and recycle the storage for you.  But this doesn't need to occur immediately -- there's no advantage to recovering the storage early vs waiting for GC to be triggered "normally".

Comment: @ Hot Licks Okay I understand now. Just printing out the information by default increases memory usage and calling the GC method cleans up the RAM used for that. How do I then go about fixing this obvious leakage problem. I removed all my statics but no major change. I have a large amount of actionListeners utilizing timers could that be the problem?

Comment: What "obvious leakage problem"?  You so far haven't described one.

Comment: @Hot Licks When I run the program the memory usage that I print out graphically is gradually increasing at all time unless I use the GC Method.

Comment: Yes, that's because of all those Strings and other things you're using in your program.  Eventually the system will automatically trigger GC and reclaim it all.

Comment: @Hot Licks Okay I am guessing it will just take awhile. So if I stare at my program for a while the RAM should drop on its own? BTW, when I do call GC my RAM usage seems to only increase by about .00001% could this mean I should have nothing to worry about?

Comment: The amount of heap in use will describe a "sawtooth" pattern -- slowly growing until GC is triggered and then dropping back down.  So long as the "valleys" are relatively stable (and GC is not happening too often) you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: Okay thanks loads! I would vote you up but can't at the moment due to low rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated, `System.gc()` is just a suggestion. It's not guaranteed to force the garbage collection, though in practice it frequently does.

The Java garbage collection runs on its own periodically. If you see that your memory is increasing over time and you're not reclaiming it, then you have a memory leak. Calling `System.gc()` won't fix that. If your memory is leaking, eventually there will be nothing to collect.

In general, you shouldn't need to force GC. As I mentioned, the GC will run on its own. You can tweak its behavior - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html.

Comment: Minor point:  If you see that the amount of occupied storage *immediately after GC runs* increases over time, then you have a (sort of) "leak".  It's perfectly normal for occupied storage to increase between GCs.

Comment: @Jeff Storey Thank you for the info. Is the leakage possibly from something I have no control over or am I just doing anything possibly in particular that could be causing this to occur?

Comment: Depends - it could be from either. It's normal to see increased memory usage when your app is doing work, but are you seeing that memory continually increase to the point where you run out? What I'm really asking is - are you sure you have a leak?

Comment: From what I see from printing out the ram usage my program would, "although it may take a long time", is increasing about .5% every second the program is running. I do not know if it is from me simply printing the RAM usage out or if it is something else. Overtime I saw that this could be a problem because the ever present OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: @ Jeff Storey When I do call the GC method it does increase, but only by like .00001%. Does this mean I don't really have a legitimate leak?

Comment: You really need to watch it over a long period of time and see if you actually are running out of memory. You should read more about how garbag collection works and what gets collected and when.

Answer (score -1):

The original problem is comes from memory leak.
Sympthom is
* because of memory leak, there are not enough memory space
* so the JVM will try to do GC again again again. 
* but still have enough memory. so GC again again.

So the System.GC or kind of GC tuning is not helpful.

To fix this problem, u have to find our where is the memory leakage point.

In JVM, there are tools that dumps current memory foot print (heapdump).

You can find out the leakage point by using this.
For more information, please refer this - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/memleaks-137499.html

Comment: Thank you for the article I will bookmark it. It is very useful.